# docker repository and tag comes up with <none>

Tags: java, dockerfile, docker-build, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to build docker image from github. I'm running the following command to build the image.

```
docker build -t test1:latest https://github.com/syndy1989/Accessibility.git
```

i get shown the below error:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> docker build -t test1:latest https://github.com/syndy1989/Accessibility.git
Sending build context to Docker daemon 78.03 MB
Step 1/13 : FROM 474614/my_repo1:windows_java_git
 ---> 2732d0c2549b
Step 2/13 : RUN git clone https://github.com/syndy1989/Accessibility.git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 57ad907abaf6
Step 3/13 : RUN mkdir C:\\axe_accessibility
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5b1f12fd22a3
Step 4/13 : WORKDIR C:\\axe_accessibility
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 196d2ceb8f72
Step 5/13 : COPY Sample.java C:\\axe_accessibility\\Sample.java
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 71ebbef33f51
Step 6/13 : COPY axe.min.js C:\\axe_accessibility\\axe.min.js
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c1804bd1708c
Step 7/13 : COPY phantomjs.exe C:\\axe_accessibility\\phantomjs.exe
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0bd0796ee072
Step 8/13 : COPY datafile.properties C:\\axe_accessibility\\datafile.properties
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 68565416a292
Step 9/13 : COPY ./lib C:\\axe_accessibility\\lib
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 348c0cbcf842
Step 10/13 : WORKDIR C:\\axe_accessibility
 ---> 3678f4222d27
Removing intermediate container c33f1296c6a9
Step 11/13 : RUN javac -cp "./lib/*;" Sample.java
 ---> Running in 7216fd466a66
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
Sample.java : The term 'Sample.java' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:95
+ ... ogressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; javac -cp ./lib/*; Sample.java
+                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Sample.java:String) [], ParentC
   ontainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

The command 'powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; javac -cp ".
/lib/*;" Sample.java' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

When I checked inside the Docker container sample.java was copied inside the folder C:/axe_accessibility. I'm able to compile inside the container but while building the image it isn't working. Any advice on this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said you're able to compile inside the container. Are you using the exact same command as the Dockerfile? From the same directory?

Comment: Yes i'm using the same command. It says 'Sample.java' is not recognized while building the image